# `name()` vs. `getName()` naming convention?

Tags: java, oop, naming-conventions

I have seen some projects (jsoup for example) are using this new getter/setter naming convention:

```
String name()
void   name(String value)
```

instead of old getter/setter convetion:

```
String getName()
void   setName(String value)
```

What are positive and negative aspects of each naming convention? When and why you think one should be preferred over the other?

Comment: The first method doesn't adhere to the JavaBeans spec, so you won't be able to use it in certain places.  For example, you'll need actual getters and setters to work with Managed Beans in JSF.

Comment: Apart from the beans aspect, I think `String s = obj.name();` reads fine, but `obj.name("new name");` is not as obvious (vs. `obj.setName("new name")`).

Answer (score 9):

The first example doesn't adhere to the [JavaBeans specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf) [Warning PDF]. There are certain frameworks like Spring, that assume this naming convention, especially when you do something in EL like `${object.name}`, which gets translated to `object.getName()`. This will fail if you don't follow the naming conventions (although there are ways to get around it).

Without getting into a discussion about when/if to use getters/setters, in general it's better to stick with the naming convention because there are fewer surprises that way, especially when you're integrating with third-party libraries or frameworks that expect things to be named according to convention.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing except readability and API style.

Some APIs accept this style and some don't, like `Spring` `injections` and `JSF` can't recognize this syntax (they explicitly require get/set for properties).

Comment: "API style": given that Spring, JSF (and JPA), etc. are so widely used in practice, that is a big "except".

Answer (score 3):

I like to simply use `name()` when the object that I'm dealing with is immutable, i.e. I would never change the value of the `name` field. When I'm dealing with a mutable object, I would use the second convention you mentioned, simply because I think it is superior in terms of readability.

Comment: I do something similar with immutable classes sometimes - I'll make the field `public final` instead of bothering to write an accessor at all.

Answer (score 2):

I always prefer using *verbs* for methods name, so this is valid also for getters and setters.

I use *nouns* only for *variables*.

Follow classic JavaBean standard make me feel more comfortable. :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the shorter style if the library is low level and I want to make it clear this component is not a JavaBean.

If in doubt, I would use the JavaBean style.